# What kind of mathematics had Max Ernst in mind?

Tags: mathematics, art

Max Ernst was a painter belonging to the Dadaistic movement. One of his paintings shows Euclid in a somewhat, well, let's say Dadaistic fashion (although fashion and Dadaism don't go along well). We can read:

> Max Ernst displayed interest in Science and Mathematics that is certainly traceable in his artistic yield, both on the level of technique and on that of content. It is reported that, after a visit at the Henri Poincare Institute in Paris, he pointed out to Christian Zervos (1889 – 1970) , a Greek art critic and publisher of the Parisian “Cahiers d’ Art” magazine, a series of models on display, representing mathematical surfaces, that struck his imagination. This encounter brought these surfaces into the artistic surrealist foreground of the time and the American artist Man Ray (1890 – 1976), after a suggestion of Zervos, produced a series of photographs of these exhibits, under the title “Mathematical Objects”. Man Ray later described these surfaces as “so unusual, as revolutionary as anything that is being done today in painting or in sculpture”, though he admitted that he understood nothing of their mathematical nature. As curious objects, reminiscent of algebraic surfaces, appear in several of Ernst’s paintings, it is quite possible that he himself made attempts to incorporate them in his works. In “Design in Nature” (1947), a painting heavily influenced by Geometry and carried out using geometric technique, Ernst provides an allusion on the mathematical nature of the world’s design. In the background, a variety of shapes and curves give birth to living forms among alternating areas of light and dark. A mathematical solid, drenched in light, dominates the foreground topped by two horn – like structures, bringing to mind the “horn” or Dupin cyclides,  two types of mathematical surfaces , forming thus an abstract ibex head.

and it goes on further. It seems a bit contrary that a Dadaist adheres to the rigor and programs of math but then again, not to follow any program allows for following a program. I could not find what Ernst's pictured math entails (excepgt that the structures he depicted resemble alebraic curves, as can be read above). How are his paintings seen by Max himself? Does he just admire math or does he want to contribute? Or is he maybe even criticizing math?